# Why does my comprehension list do not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello here is my code in Python :

```
test = [test[i-1]+3 if i > 0 else 4 for i in range(0, 10)]
```

My problem is that I want to use a comprehension list for this :

```
test[0] = 4
test[i] = test[i-1]+3 if i > 0
```

I want to use a comprehension list to do this.

Comment: The `test` variable is only assigned at the end of your comprehension list evaluation. So `test[i-1]` won't be defined for `i = 2`. Also, for future questions, please add the error that the compiler is giving you.

Comment: If the name `test` refers to anything at all, it's not list currently under construction.

Comment: @MondKin Whether `test[i-1]` is defined for *any* value of `i` is completely independent of the list comprehension.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any kind of recursion for this. The final list you want is

```
[4, 7, 10, 13, ...]  # 4 + 0, 4 + 3, 4 + 6, 4 + 9, ...
```

which you can define simply as

```
test = [4 + 3*i for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need recursion (in case of a change in formula or conditions), you can use this recursive solution:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def f(n):
  return f(n - 1) + 3 if n > 0 else 4

test = [f(i) for i in range(10)]

print(test)
```

Output:

```
[4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version, without recursion, using `itertools.accumulate`:

```
from itertools import accumulate
print(list(accumulate(4 if i==0 else 3 for i in range(10))))
```

Prints:

```
[4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31]
```